# How to add a picture in html page in Spring application

Tags: java, image, spring

I have got a `Spring` application and I am using `JBoss 7.1.1` to run my server.

When I click submit, it goes to my controller which invokes method from another java class. This method creates a picture:

```
...
private String filePath = "./qrcode.png";
...
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
...
```

finally, the picture is saved in directory:

```
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin
```

Now, I want to show this image in my html page. In the controler I added:

```
model.addAttribute("qrimage", "/qrcodes/qrcode.png");
```

in html code I have got (I use `thymeleaf`):

```
<td style="text-align: center">
    <img th:attr="src=@{${qrimage}} , title=#{background}, alt=#{background}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
</td>
```

and when I access my page I see: `??background_fr??` instead of my picture. When I use in my java class:

```
private String filePath = "./../standalone/deployments/myproject-web.war/qrcode.png";
```

instead of

```
private String filePath = "./qrcode.png";
```

everything works.

In my `mvc-servlet.xml` I have got:

```
<mvc:resources location="/qrcodes" mapping="/qrcodes/**" />
```

I would like to avoid **hardcoded paths** in my code such as `./../standalone/deployments/myproject-web.war/qrcode.png`

Somone can help me?

---

An edited controller:

```
package com.my.package.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.my.package.smsgenerator.QrCodeGenerator;

@Controller
public class QrCodeGeneratorController extends AbstractController implements
        ApplicationContextAware {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/qrcode")
    public String getPage(Model m,
            @ModelAttribute("subscription") final QrCodeGenerator subscription) {
        return "qrcode";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscribeth", params = { "save" })
    public String save(final QrCodeGenerator subscription,
            final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model)
            throws IOException {

        subscription.buildQRCCode();

        model.addAttribute("qrimage", applicationContext.getResource("/qrcodes/qrcode.png").getFile().getAbsolutePath());

        return "forward:/qrcode";
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = ctx;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it with the `Resource` class via context:

```
Resource template = ctx.getResource("some/resource/path/myTemplate.png");
```

Resource class has methods like `getURL()`, `getFile()`, etc, which you can use to get the path to your picture.

More about Spring resources: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/resources.html

Comment: In which place I should you use?

Comment: You should know this, because I don't know the structure of your code, but this could work: model.addAttribute("qrimage", getContext().getResource("/qrcodes/qrcode.png").getFile().getAbsolutePath());

Comment: I think it is the same context where you acquired you model. Maybe this post can help you: [Three ways to get the context in Spring 3.0](http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/spring-application-context/)

Comment: Hi, following your link I edited my controller but I still cannot see my picture. I edited my post and I added my controller. Could you take a look? Thanks in advance.